# How do I calculate two text boxes and display the answer in another?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add the two text boxes and show the result in a third, whenever I try to add the third box, it makes it invalid. Any suggestions?
Here is my code!

```
    <br>
    <br>
    <p4>Calculate Two Fields</p4>
    <p4 id="answer"></p4>
    <br>
    <br>

    Number 1<input type="text" id="num1" <br>
    <br>
    Number 2<input type="text" id="num2" <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>

    <script>
        function calculate() {
            var field1 = document.getElementById(num1).value;
            var field2 = document.getElementById(num2).value;

            var result = parseFloat(field1) + parseFloat(field2)

            if (!isNaN(result))

            {
                document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "The answer is " + result;

            }
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`getElementById('num1')` here `id` should be in quote, otherwise it will be treated as variable.

Also you forgot the `}` at the end

```js
function calculate() {
            var field1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
            var field2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;

            var result = parseFloat(field1) + parseFloat(field2);
            if (!isNaN(result))

            {
                document.getElementById("answer").textContent= "The answer is " + result;

            }
      }
```

```html
<br>
    <br>
    <p4>Calculate Two Fields</p4>
    <p4 id="answer"></p4>
    <br>
    <br>

    Number 1<input type="text" id="num1" <br>
    <br>
    Number 2<input type="text" id="num2" <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Please don't use ```.innerHTML``` unless you are assigning ```HTML``` elements.. Instead use ```textContent```..

Comment: What about  if decimal number?

Comment: This worked!!! Thank you so much! I have been trying to figure it out for two day, thank you for helping me realize this!

Answer (score 0):

Try.....

```js
$("#second").keyup(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.smtab_tot').each(function(_i, e) {
    var val = parseFloat(e.value);
    if (!isNaN(val))
      total += val;
  });
  $('#total').val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

input 1 : <input type="number" class="smtab_tot" id="first">
<br> 
input 2 : <input type="number" class="smtab_tot" id="second">
<br> 
total : <input type="text" id="total">
```

Comment: There is no jquery involved in the question and tags as well..

Comment: This is called using Thor's hammer to kill an ant

Answer (score 0):

I cant see any mistake except `;` or `}` .

Its better to use `onchange` or other events events to remove clicking  to get better ui/ux.

But you can do it with `angularjs` better.you can use `ng-model` for each input and in third input write `{{model1+model2}}`.

You can do it with `vue.js` too .the different is that you should use `vmodel` instead of `ng-model`.